# Regards to Registering and Unregistered User Account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have a question. How can you register yourself with an openid, if you have used the site as an unregistered user and now want to register under the same website name and id. It seems to make me create a whole name. How can I use my open id from my unregistered profile in creating a registered profile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To convert an unregistered account from unregistered to registered

1. You must hold the browser cookie of the unregistered account (these accounts are cookie-based by definition).<sup>1</sup>
2. Click the 'register' link at the top of every page.
3. After adding credentials, your account will convert from unregistered to registered.

If you have accidentally created a duplicate account -- that is, you now have BOTH registered and unregistered accounts, email the address printed at the bottom of every page with URLs to both accounts and we can merge them.

<sup>1</sup> If you do not hold the cookie, use the [account recovery page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and it will email you a link to reinstantiate the cookie. That's assuming you have provided a valid email address to us originally ... we don't check.

Comment: When I clicked register, and in the box where you can type I believe a name or username, it tells me that it is already taken, meaning the unregistered account that I am using. This process seems to be overly complicated and I think that this site has a lot of downfalls in area of the capabilities of which the user is granted.

Comment: Why is it, after I click register and use the openid on the unregistered user page in the box where it says manually enter your openid, it says: "Unable to login with your openid provider. No openid endpoint found."

Comment: @thomas I highly recommend you click the Google, MyOpenId, or Facebook buttons when registering. Manual entry is for the very advanced user only.